# What is the difference between nhibernate and entity framework in batching?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, entity-framework, batching

I want to select one of the above orm.
What is the difference between nhibernate and entity framework in batching?

Comment: How do you mean the difference in batching? What characteristics are you interested in?

Comment: Is EF supports batching operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate can:

- Send multiple updates/inserts/deletes at once
- Load multiple proxies of a type at once
- Load multiple collections of a type at once
- Execute object oriented DML statements
- Manually group queries in a single roundtrip (multiqueries, futures)

EF can:

- None of the above

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that EF natively doesn't have any command batching so every update, insert or delete is executed in separate round trip to the database - but in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407348/batching-db-commands-in-entity-framework-4-0) are some links to workarounds. EF also doesn't have any alternative to NHibernate future queries (way to batch multiple queries to single database round trip).

Comment: Is this still the case 2 years later with the lack of future queries?

Comment: @MikeCole: If we talk about EF the answer is yes. There are some open source projects making this little bit better but it is still far from real built-in solution.