# EF 4.1 Seeking ideas on how to speed up adding of rows

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am populating my database from online data using the loop like (simplified, with no error checking):

```
foreach (var catalog in catalogs)
{
   var result = Items(catalog, state, context);
   while (result != null)
   {
      result.ForEach(r => context.DbContext.Items.Add(r));
      context.DbContext.SaveChanges();
      result = Items(catalog, state, context);
   }
}
```

Code takes some time to get XML response from the server and to decode it into XElement, using XElement.Load on response stream. It is decoded into a list of items which contains max 50 items - that is what I requested from the server in each loop pass. That chunk gets saved to a table right away because of SaveChanges call..

8/10 of the loop time is spent either on adding items to DbContext or in SaveChanges call or on both. Communication with the remote server and decoding response XML into a list of entities is 2/10.

How can I increase the efficiency of storing data into the database, while still staying with EF?

I am aware that I can bulk-load the database from XML, but that will force me to figure out SQL statements that I need to write, because several related tables get updated with the SaveChanges call above, and so I start losing the advantages of using EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: You cannot speed your insertion process with pure EF because EF has [very poor performance for bulk / batch data processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407348/batching-db-commands-in-entity-framework-4-0). You have two problems:

- Adding entity to context has some costs and this costs increases with every entity already present in the context. To avoid this you can try to call `SavaChanges` after each call to `Add`or even try to use new context for every batch or even every call to `Add`.
- EF makes a separate database roundtrip for every record you want to insert, update or delete so it generally doesn't matter how often do you call `SaveChanges`. Avoiding this is mostly possible only when using direct SQL and creating single `SqlCommand` executing all inserts at once.

If you want to increase performance use direct SQL.

Comment: Sigh. Initially I expected that constructing XElement from a stream and then creating a list of POCO objects from its XElement children would be the bottleneck!