# Deleting all related entities in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity called Entry connected to multiple TimeWindows. I want to clear all time windows, then add new ones. At first I tried:

```
target.TimeWindows.Clear();
```

but this didn't really delete them, and only *tried* to remove the relationship, which caused an exception since there is foreign key from TimeWindows to Entry. Then I thought I should do this:

```
foreach (var tw in target.TimeWindows)
    context.DeleteObject(tw);
```

but this throw an exception as well, since the collection was modified inside the `foreach` statement. So I thought of this:

```
while (target.TimeWindows.Count > 0)
    context.DeleteObject(target.TimeWindows.Last());
```

But now I am a bit concerned about using `Count` property, because it might cause a `SQL SELECT COUNT` statement to be executed. Does it? If yes, how can I delete all time windows in Entity Framework?

Comment: No, the `Count` will not trigger a `SELECT COUNT` on the database, it is worse :-). It will do a `SELECT * FROM TimeWindows WHERE TargetId = @P0` and do a count on the in-memory collection.

Comment: Oh my God!! Then what is your suggestion?!

Comment: When you want to delete an entity, it should first be loaded into memory. All O/RM tools work this way. Entity Framework is no different. If the performance is too low, write a stored procedure that does the delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling count on navigation property will cause select only if lazy loading is enabled and the property is not loaded yet. So the first call can cause something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TimeWindows WHERE TargetId = @targetId
```

and all count evaluations will just execute on loaded data.

You can also use this to avoid the second exception:

```
foreach (var tw in target.TimeWindows.ToList())
    context.DeleteObject(tw);
```

Or you can change your database and model to support [identifying relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922228/entity-framework-4-delete-object-from-entity-collection/4925040#4925040) (FK to parent will became part of TimeWindow's PK) and in such case your first code snippet will work.

Comment: But executing ToList() means fetching all the time windows, right?! Well, if that is right, then it is even worse actually :-)

Comment: In SQL, I could really execute one statement and delete all the time windows, which is something like `DELETE * FROM TimeWindows WHERE EntryId = ...`, so is it possible to de the same in Entity Framework?

Comment: Executing `ToList` will fetch data only once. Batch deletes are not possible without [little hacking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776964/what-is-the-recommended-practice-to-update-or-delete-multiple-entities-in-entity/9777017#9777017) but when using this approach changes performed in the database will not be reflected in your context.