# How Entity Framework works in case of batch insert and update data

Tags: entity-framework

I use MS data access application block for interaction with database and I saw its performance is good. When I like to add 100 or more records then I send those 100 records in xml format to a stored procedure and from there I do a bulk insert. Now I have to use Entity Framework. I haven't ever used EF before so I am not familiar with EF and how it works.

In another forum I asked a question like "How Entity Framework works in case of batch insert and update data" and got answer

> From my experience, EF does not support batch insert or batch update.
>
> What it does is that it will issue an individual insert or update statement, but it will wrap all of them in a transaction if you add all of your changes to the dbcontect before calling SaveChanges().

Is it true that EF can not handle batch insert/update? In case of batch insert/update EF inserts data in loop? If there are 100 records which we need to commit at once then EF can not do it?

If it is not right then please guide me how one should write code as a result EF can do batch insert/update. Also tell me the trick how to see what kind of SQL it will generate.

If possible please guide me with sample code for batch insert/update with EF. also tell me which version of EF support true batch operation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes EF is not a Bulk load, Update tool.
You can of course put a a few K entries and commit (SaveChanges)
But when you have serious volumes of speed is critical, use SQL.

see [Batch update/delete EF5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751258/batch-update-delete-ef5) as an example on the topic

Comment: thanks for good link.if i update a particular one or two field in table where millions record there then what happen.i heard that when we update table by EF then it update all the fields....is it true? how can i see what sql EF is generating at the time of insert/update ?

Comment: thats a second question. but no, EF does correctly update Set commands. but it does so for a KEY=x.   Again you want SQL commands for Update X where ...set a=b.   EF is an ORM an excellent ORM but it works with Objects. Perhaps in a future release Bulk activity is added. For now you use SQL statements for Bulk activity

Comment: sorry no very clear what u r saying.can u tell me EF handle update if i update 2 field out 10 field. thanks

Comment: yes ef does UPDATE SET 2 of 10 fields. BUT 1 object at a time