# Update multiple rows in Entity Framework from a list of ids

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-update

I am trying to create a query for Entity Framework that will allow me to take a list of ids and update a field associated with them.

Example in SQL:

```
UPDATE Friends
SET msgSentBy = '1234'
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How do I convert the above into Entity Framework?

Comment: What is your database platform Oracle mysql ..

Comment: My database is Microsoft SQL

Comment: There are two open source projects allowing this: [EntityFramework.Extended](https://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended) and E[ntity Framework Extensions](http://efe.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The only correct answer to this is: you can't. Sure, you can pull all matching `Friend`s from the database and update their property `msgSentBy` and save changes. But EF will fire `UPDATE` statements for each individual record. That's not at all the same as a one-statement bulk update. As said, look for a third-party library that offers bulk update.

Comment: @SamuelLiew why move my answer to a comment, it is an answer and a useful one at that?

Comment: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592596/update-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-from-a-list-of-ids/21592733#21592733) is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424146/could-be-an-irrelevant-modification-of-answer-be-flagged-as-a-plagiarized-answer).

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Something like below:

```
var idList = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
using (var db = new SomeDatabaseContext())
{
    var friends = db.Friends.Where(f => idList.Contains(f.ID)).ToList();
    friends.ForEach(a => a.msgSentBy='1234');
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can update multiple fields as below:

```
friends.ForEach(a =>
                      {
                         a.property1 = value1;
                         a.property2 = value2;
                      });
```

Comment: can i update more than one field in the foreach above you did just sent by which is exactly what i asked for. just curious if you could do more? Also doesn't look like SubmitChanges quite works anymore. I am using the latest entity framework. Maybe SaveChanges()?

Comment: `ForEach` is a method on `List`, and it's generally discouraged to use because it's not a very functional-way of programming.  Just use `foreach` *(the operator)*.

Comment: Using this solution generates one update query for each element in the list. Is there a way to get EF to do just one query like in the question? (`UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField = SomeValue WHERE Id IN (...)`)

Comment: Be aware that this is a pretty inefficient way to go about this from a database perspective. Not only does this issue a big select statement involving every row from the Friends table, but it issues a separate UPDATE command for every record that is updated. So rather than issuing one command you are issues potentially many many commands as well as streaming a bunch of data out of your database.

Comment: @user1334007 any solution to avoid this?

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, basically what you want to do is issue a SQL command like "UPDATE Friends SET msgSentBy = '1234' WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)". I don't think that EF has direct support for doing that. I believe there are some 3rd party solutions to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751258/batch-update-delete-ef5) but I haven't used them. The other options is to use raw ADO.NET instead of EF.

Comment: This is also getting the data first from the DB. Is there anything else that we can use without getting the data first?

Comment: This should NOT be the accepted answer, it's pretty inefficient and will cause the db to run out of memory pretty fast,

Comment: Entity Framework 7 solves this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates

Comment: You cant  still  do in Entity Framework 7  WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)  What they did is you can update a range like  WHERE ID >1

Answer (score 19):

The best way to do a massive update with Entity Framework 7 is like this:

```
var idList = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
context.Friends
       .Where(f => idList.Contains(f.ID))
       .ExecuteUpdate(f => f.SetProperty(x => x.Name, x => $"Updated {x.Name}"));
```

The advantage of this is that it doesn't retrieve all the records. It just sends an update query.

Reference: *[ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete (Bulk updates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates)*

Comment: How you can update as in topic Where id in (1,2,7,9)?

Comment: @dawiddebinski I've updated this answer to match the question, and explained why it's better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Thats the way to go!

Comment: Too bad those are "only" EF7+ compatible, so there's no .NET Framework relevance here - darn it! Oh well - time to upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

The [`IQueryable.ToQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0) method introduced in Entity Framework Core 5.0 may help with this scenario, if you are willing to have some raw SQL appearing in your code. This method will generate SQL that can be included in a raw SQL query to perform a bulk update of records identified by that query.

For example:

```
using var context = new DbContext();

var ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var query = context.Friends.Where(_ => ids.Contains(_.id)).Select(_ => _.id);

var sql = $"UPDATE Friends SET msgSentBy = {{0}} WHERE id IN ({query.ToQueryString()})";

context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, "1234");
```

The major drawback of this approach is the use of raw SQL. However I don't know of any reasonable way to avoid that with current Entity Framework Core capabilities - you're stuck with this caveat, or the caveats of other answers posted here such as:

- Introducing a dependency on another library like https://github.com/yangzhongke/Zack.EFCore.Batch.
- Using `DbContext.SaveChanges()` which will update records one at a time rather than doing a bulk update.

If (when) the following issue is addressed in the future then we are likely to get a better answer here: [Bulk (i.e. set-based) CUD operations (without loading data into memory) #795](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/795)

Answer (score 4):

```
var idList=new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
var friendsToUpdate = await Context.Friends.Where(f => 
    idList.Contains(f.Id).ToListAsync();

foreach(var item in previousEReceipts)
{
  item.msgSentBy = "1234";
}
```

You can use foreach to update each element that meets your condition.

Here is an example in a more generic way:

```
var itemsToUpdate = await Context.friends.Where(f => f.Id == <someCondition>).ToListAsync();

foreach(var item in itemsToUpdate)
{
   item.property = updatedValue;
}
Context.SaveChanges()
```

In general you will most probably use async methods with await for db queries.

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything to the existing answer. It basically just repeats it.

Comment: the main difference is to use foreach instead of friends.ForEach

Comment: The problem with this answer is it will read all the friends out of the DB into memory, alter them and then save them again, rather than executing a single update query in SQL to the DB.

Comment: *foreach instead of friends.ForEach* That's totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a library to batch delete or update records with a round trip on [EF Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework#History) 5.

Sample code is as follows:

```
await ctx.DeleteRangeAsync(b => b.Price > n || b.AuthorName == "zack yang");

await ctx.BatchUpdate()
.Set(b => b.Price, b => b.Price + 3)
.Set(b=>b.AuthorName,b=>b.Title.Substring(3,2)+b.AuthorName.ToUpper())
.Set(b => b.PubTime, b => DateTime.Now)
.Where(b => b.Id > n || b.AuthorName.StartsWith("Zack"))
.ExecuteAsync();
```

GitHub repository: *[Zack.EFCore.Batch](https://github.com/yangzhongke/Zack.EFCore.Batch)*
Report: *[How to batch delete or update in Entity Framework Core 5](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetcore/comments/k1esra/how_to_batch_delete_or_update_in_entity_framework/)*

Comment: good, but gpl license :(

Answer (score -1):

For those who are searching for a *bulk update* (like me):

Based on Microsoft EF documents, in the *Performance* section (Efficient Update), if you want to do bulk update, you better use executing raw SQL to improve the performance.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("UPDATE [Employees] SET [Salary] = [Salary] + 1000");
```

*[Efficient Updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating)*

Comment: @Twenty: It doesn't look like a new question. It looks like an answer.

Comment: @PeterMortensen You are totally correct. I guess I commented it because it doesn't quite  solve the issue of the OP, as you are not updating the rows by ids. Anyhow, my comment was wrong, thanks :)