# Force Entity Framework to update several records in one round trip.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have to update multiple records in EF and I've come up with the following two methods:

Method 1: `ExecuteSqlCommand` (direct SQL)

```
customDB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
@"UPDATE  dbo.UserInfo
SET     dbo.UserInfo.Email = dbo.IAMUser.Email,
        dbo.UserInfo.Mobile = dbo.IAMUser.Phone
FROM    dbo.UserInfo
        INNER JOIN dbo.IAMUserMapping ON dbo.UserInfo.UserID = dbo.IAMUserMapping.fUserId
        INNER JOIN dbo.IAMUser ON IAMUser.IAMID = IAMUserMapping.fIAMID
WHERE   dbo.IAMUser.IAMID = @iamid ", new SqlParameter("@iamid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = IAMID });
```

Method 2: Linq foreach:

```
var ui = from userInfo in customDB.UserInfo
     join userMapping in customDB.IAMUserMapping 
         on userInfo.UserID equals userMapping.fUserId
     join iamUser in customDB.IAMUser 
         on userMapping.IAMUser.IAMID equals iamUser.IAMID
     where iamUser.IAMID == IAMID
     select new
     {
         userInfo.UserID,
         iamUser.Email,
         iamUser.Phone
     };

foreach (var x1 in ui)
{
    var u = new UserInfo
    {
        UserID = x1.UserID,
        Email = x1.Email,
        Mobile = x1.Phone
    };
    customDB.UserInfo.Attach(u);
    var entry = customDB.Entry(u);
    entry.Property(e => e.Email).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(e => e.Mobile).IsModified = true;
}
customDB.SaveChanges();
```

Method #1 is the most efficient, resulting in a single SQL query.

Method #2 is as efficient on the SQL Server side of things, but it generates a lot more round trips to the server. 1 select to get the records, then 1 update for each record that is updated.

Method #2 will give a compile time error if anything in the DB is changed, while #1 will give a run time error.

What do people consider the best practice in cases like these?

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: There's a well known bug in SO's markup that causes issues with code formatting within numbered lists.  I just rejected an edit that made it even worse, so I can't fix now.  Just [edit] and get rid of the numbered list and format your code properly as code.

Comment: I saw it on post, fixed it by writing method in front. Ty for the edit.

Comment: *the best practice* makes this question off-topic at Stack Overflow (opinion-based, and hard to answer because it's up to you to weigh the trade-offs of both methods). *any other way to optimize this query?* Is a better question to ask here, but even then one may argue that CodeReview is a better fit.

Comment: The question is more about if these two methods are the best way to do it, or if there is a 3rd way that is strictly better.

Comment: In situations like this your 1st approach is the best especially when it concerns a large number of records. An alternate approach is to use a Stored Proc which pretty much results again is something very similar to your first example.

Comment: Don't you have navigation properties connecting userInfo, userMapping and IAMUserMapping? If so remove your joins. e.g. UserInfo.IAMUserMapping.IAMUser ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592596/update-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-from-a-list-of-ids

Comment: Paul: IAMUserMapping and IAMUser dos have navigational mappings, userInfo does not map to either of them. I've written it out so it's easier to compare to the SQL join.

Answer (score 0):

With first approach problems that you may faced will be much more critical and harder to solve, e.g. when renaming/restructuring of entities. Compile time errors are much better, easy to solve then runtime ones.

Also, I am not sure how ExecuteSqlCommand method works, but looks like this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.
So, I will definitelly choose linq approach.

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand  is safe as long as you use parameters. The generated SQL if you trace using profiler is equal.

Comment: I disagree, on point 1 but this is more a matter of opinion. On point 2 it is parameterized so there is no risk of sql injection. In the OPs example the code even passes in a `SqlParameter` instance to illustrate it.

Comment: it depends of what you need, as some people answered you can do a store procedure, Now if you want to consume a large data, this is simple you can put this into a hosted background and run in the night there are less people doing transactions. but for sure you can parameters if people know how to do with native SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc.