# Update Multiple Rows in Entity Framework from one id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a query for Entity Framework that will allow me to take one `id` and update a field associated with it.

Example in SQL:

```
UPDATE Recibo
SET Estado = 3
WHERE IdApartado IN (7)
```

How do I convert the above to Entity Framework?

Comment: have a look on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592596/update-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-from-a-list-of-ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it, perhaps, the easiest way would be to read the records, edit them and save them, as explained [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/crud-operation-in-connected-scenario-entity-framework.aspx):

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    // read 
    var records = dbContext.Recibo.Where(r => r.IdApartado == 7).ToList();

    // update
    foreach (r in records)
    {
        r.Estado = 3;
    }

    // save
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do `in` clause in EF:

**first is** `Contains`:

```
return dbContext.Query<R>.Where(r => subset.Contains(r.Id)).ToList();
```

**second is `foreach` with `contains`**:

```
 return dbContext.Query<R>.Where(r => subset.Contains(r.Id)).ToList().ForEach(a => a.id = "7");
```

this is because the best equivalent for sql `in` in EF  is `Contains`.