# batch updates using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, batch-updates

Can anyone suggest me how to deal with batch updates using Entity Framework?

For ex: Updating a field for a list (List) of between 100 and 1000 Id's, which the primary key. Calling each update separately seem to be to much overhead and takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Until you call `SaveChanges()` none of the data is updated in the database so you can make how many changes you'd like.

You can take a look at a Unit of Work design pattern if you want a more structured way of saving changes to the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply..But Adrian did you get my point? i know that until i call SaveChanges() nothing is updated to database. what i need all about batch update.

Comment: Hi, you can check this thread out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751258/batch-update-delete-ef5 hope it answers some of your questions