# Update a value for an entire set without using foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently looping through my *Contact* table and setting their `IsCustomer` flag to false using a `foreach` loop.

```
using (var db = new Entities(cs))
{
    foreach (var contact in db.Contacts)
        contact.IsCustomer = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I notice that this process is taking a long time. Is there a way to set all my *Contacts* `IsCustomer` flag to false without setting them one by one? Or is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: You can execute update query directly for performance reason. using db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Comment: The actual database update is going to be orders of magnitude more expensive than the time spent updating the in-memory objects.  That portion is almost certainly negligible in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        int changed = Entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update Contact set IsCustomer = 0");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by  @Jeroen Vannevel
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751258/batch-update-delete-ef5)
this question would solve your problem hopefully,

Best is to use this
[EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#batch-update-and-delete)
but if you do not want to add this to your project then
you can use a simple SQL statement.
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.SqlCommand( 
        "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1"); 
}
```