# Update a List of entries using a List of ID's in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using the following code to store a list of connectionID's in a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> connectionIds =
                    connectedUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.ConnectionId).ToList();
```

I need to update the Database to set the connection status to `false` when it finds the corresponding ID's. So far, I am using the following code:

```
if (connectionIds.Any())
                {
                    foreach (string connectionId in connectionIds)
                    {
                        Connection curConn = db.Connection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionID == connectionId);
                        if (curConn != null)
                            curConn.Connected = false;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
```

However, this makes a call to the DB for each connection... Is there any simple way to update the connection in an easier process?

Comment: It actually makes two calls - one to load the object, one to save the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. This will result in a single query for loading the connection objects. Once you have the result of the query, loop through the results to update the `Connected` flag, and then save the changes.

```
List<string> connectionIds = ...;

if (connectionIds.Any()) {
    var data = db.Connection
        .Where(x => connectionIds.Contains(x.ConnectionID))
        .ToList();
    foreach (var item in data) {
        item.Connected = false;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please note that the list is 'given' to SQL using parameters, and there is a maximum amount of parameters for a query (I think somewhere around 2000), so if you expect more connection-ids, then this solution will not work.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks for that info! Never knew about these limits at all.. Will check it out IF I ever get that amount (Shouldn't though).

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform batch updates in one SQL statement with EF. EF doesn't support this in a straightforward manner. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777188/871910) for a possible solution.